# Angular 6 aspnetcore angular/compiler-cli to be 2.3.1 or greater

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I create an application with visual studio 2017

- ASP.Net core
- angular

the template come with angular 4 
I updated for angular 6.1.3
but I get this error 
**crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "6.1.3".**

here is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "WebApplication1",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "6.1.3",
        "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
        "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "chai": "4.0.2",
        "css": "2.2.1",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
        "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "html-loader": "0.4.5",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "json-loader": "0.5.4",
        "karma": "1.7.0",
        "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
        "preboot": "4.5.2",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "6.2.2",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
        "typescript": "2.9.2",
        "url-loader": "0.5.9",
        "webpack": "2.5.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^6.1.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0"
      }
    }
```